java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler. when upgrading jersey version from 2.27 to 2.34

Issue when upgrading Jersey @2.27 to Jersey @2.34
POM FILE
<xom_version>1.2.5</xom_version>
<jersey_client_version>2.6</jersey_client_version>
<javax_inject_version>2.2.0</javax_inject_version>
<jaxrs_ri_version>2.6.0</jaxrs_ri_version>
<joor_version>0.9.14</joor_version>
<jersey_common_version>2.34</jersey_common_version>
<gson_version>2.8.9</gson_version>
<jersey_guava_version>2.6</jersey_guava_version>
<hk2_api_version>2.2.0</hk2_api_version>


You may follow some common practises to resolve this type of  issue
Firstly : Do a clean build of your project using
 mvn clean install

Secondly Check the release notes of your desired jersey version whether it contains the below mothod..you may navigate to the class to check for this method.
org.glassfisj.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessage.WARNING_PROPERTIES() 

Thirdly check whether there exist multiple version of jersey in your project root , use the below command to check
mvn dependency:tree 

